# Enable Annotation Buttons using R's Highcharter Library

Tags: r, highcharts

I am using the `highcharter` library for a project in R and really need the ability to draw freehand lines on the chart. I see the highcharts library can add annotations to the chart. Is there a way to enable the annotation buttons on my chart with the `highcharter` library? 
https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations
Below is a code example that uses the `hc_annotations()`. I’m not sure what needs to be added to the `hc_annotations()` to enable the buttons.

```
library("highcharter")
data("citytemp")

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "New York", data = citytemp$new_york)
hc 


hc %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london, type = "area") %>% 
  hc_rm_series(name = "New York") %>% 
  hc_annotations(list(enabledButtons=TRUE, xValue = 10, yValue = 10, title =list(text = 'Annotated chart!')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to add the default annotation buttons in `highcharter`.  After a couple attempts with `hc_annotations()` it seems just passing a list of options to the initial `highchart()` call might be easier.

```
library("highcharter")
data("citytemp")

hc_opts <- list(enabledButtons=TRUE)
hc <- highchart(hc_opts) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "New York", data = citytemp$new_york)
hc
```

#### output

[image: highchart annotation buttons]

Comment: I ran the code but I'm not seeing the buttons on the chart. I need to be able to draw freehand lines and add annotation text on the chart.

Comment: i just reran the code in a fresh R session and put a screenshot of the output (R version 3.3.2 with `packageVersion("highcharter")==‘0.5.0’`).  are the buttons in the corner of my screenshot what you're looking for?

Comment: additionally i reproduced the plot on both windows and mac (using the same version info in my above comment)

Comment: I was running an earlier version that 0.5.0. It seems packageVersion("highcharter")==‘0.5.0’ is required. Its running now.